# Can I weight content based on taxonomy in Views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a list of nodes. Each node has a taxonomy term associated with it. Is it possible to give certain taxonomy terms more weight than others? For example, if I gave term 1 more weight than term 2, all nodes associated with term 1 would be listed first. I'll attach an image to illustrate what I mean. I can generate this behavior by creating multiple displays for the view, but I've prefer to contain all of the logic within a single view display. Any tips would be helpful!

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the admin config for the view? Did you attach a weight field to your tax terms?

Comment: You have to add a Sort By filter and sort on Taxonomy: Weight